# The simplest way to track Google Analytics without JavaScript?

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to track Google Analytics on my site, when JavaScript is not available?

Comment: Is it a blog? Some free versions include statistics.

Comment: As an aside, would love to know why you'd like to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done. All Google Analytics seems to do is ultimately request an image file with analytic data appended to the URL. You can call that URL directly from your PHP or other server side code to [achieve the same effect](http://www.vdgraaf.info/google-analytics-without-javascript.html).

Comment: Here's the actual [documentation](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/) for this. (That post is from 2007 so you never know when there might be some breaking change.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

The parameters of Google Analytics .gif request are, surprisingly, documented at Google:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gaTrackingTroubleshooting#gifParameters

A similar, but more popular question, that discusses these issues is also available on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027660/generate-google-analytics-events-utm-gif-requests-serverside